# How can I migrate a RedisCacheManager with default expiration to Spring Data Redis 2.0?

Tags: spring, redis, spring-data, spring-data-redis

I'm upgrading a project which uses Spring Data Redis to 2.x.  Previously, the cache manager could be configured with a default expiration using [RedisCacheManager.setDefaultExpiration(defaultExpireTime)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/1.8.x/api/org/springframework/data/redis/cache/RedisCacheManager.html#setDefaultExpiration-long-).  This option does not seem to exist in 2.x.  What is the equivalent in 2.x?  Is it [RedisCacheConfiguration.entryTtl(ttl)](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/redis/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/data/redis/cache/RedisCacheConfiguration.html#entryTtl-java.time.Duration-), or something else?

I'm probably missing something, but I'm not finding a migration guide to Spring Data Redis 2.x.  Does such a migration guide exist?

In short, I would like to migrate the following code to Redis 2.x:

```
public CacheManager cacheManager() {
    RedisCacheManager redisCacheManager = new RedisCacheManager(redisTemplate());
    redisCacheManager.setDefaultExpiration(DEFAULT_EXPIRATION_SECONDS);
    return redisCacheManager;
}

public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate() {
    RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
    template.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory());
    return template;
}
```

Is the following equivalent?  If not, what would be the equivalent code in Redis 2.x?

```
public CacheManager cacheManager() {
    return RedisCacheManager.builder(redisConnectionFactory())
            .cacheDefaults(RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig().entryTtl(DEFAULT_EXPIRATION_DURATION))
            .build();
}
```

Comment: Yes, it's equivalent

Answer (score 9):

Originally, I was running the following source code and dependencies...

```
    @Bean(value ="redisTemplate")
public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory) {
    RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<String, Object>();
    redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory);
    return redisTemplate;
}

@Bean
public CacheManager cacheManager(RedisTemplate redisTemplate){
    RedisCacheManager cacheManager = new RedisCacheManager(redisTemplate);
    cacheManager.setDefaultExpiration(resourceConfigValue.getCacheExpireSeconds());
    return cacheManager;
}
```

org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.5.10.RELEASE

org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis:1.5.10.RELEASE

**I've confirmed this idea is working as expected...**

```
    @Bean(value ="redisTemplate")
public RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory) {
    RedisTemplate<String, Object> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<String, Object>();
    redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory);
    return redisTemplate;
}

@Bean
public CacheManager cacheManager(RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory) {
    Duration expiration = Duration.ofSeconds(resourceConfigValue.getCacheExpireSeconds());
    return RedisCacheManager.builder(redisConnectionFactory)
            .cacheDefaults(RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig().entryTtl(expiration)).build();
}
```

org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.0.2.RELEASE

org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis:2.0.2.RELEASE

Comment: How have you confirmed that?

Comment: After making these changes I ran my unit test suite, which is about 275 unit and integration testcases. This including accessing values from the Redis Server where I store the Application Context for my security and user object. Everything seems to work as before, now if there is new feature(s), I have not the time to dive deeper yet - but thank you for your example because with all the recent changes in major versions, I'm not seeing the documentation updates and this article helps me get moving forward.

Answer (score 2):

put this into application.yml

spring.cache.redis.time-to-live: 60s

change 60 to your DEFAULT_EXPIRATION_SECONDS

Answer (score 1):

With new redis version, you can no longer pass RedisTemplate anymore.

This is how you can set RedisCacheManager expiration (ex: 1 hour expiration)

```
@Bean
public RedisCacheManager redisCacheManager(LettuceConnectionFactory lettuceConnectionFactory) {
    RedisCacheConfiguration redisCacheConfiguration = RedisCacheConfiguration.defaultCacheConfig()
            .disableCachingNullValues()
            .entryTtl(Duration.ofHours(1));

   return RedisCacheManager.RedisCacheManagerBuilder.fromConnectionFactory(lettuceConnectionFactory)
                    .cacheDefaults(redisCacheConfiguration).build();

}
```

If no entryTtl is set, there is no expiration.

Tested with spring redis 2.4.1

PS: You can also define two RedisCacheManager bean, one with @Primary annotation. This way you can pass the timeoutCacheManager in the @Cacheable / @CachePut annotation like so.

```
@Cacheable(value = "your.cache.name", cacheManager = "timeoutCacheManager")
```